# eclipselink multitenant: retrieve wrong user.roles

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, multi-tenant

Use EclipseLink 2.5.1.

Role is single table multitenant. Each tenant has own roles.
User is not multitenant, shared by all tenants.

User/Role: ManyToMany mapping.

User has a collection of roles:

```
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "UserRole", 
             joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "uId")},  
             inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "rId")})
  public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
  }
```

Role does not have a reference to User.

```
<entity class="Role" > 
    <multitenant>
        <tenant-discriminator-column name="tenantId" context-property="tenant.id"
            discriminator-type="INTEGER"/>      
    </multitenant>  
</entity>
```

User is not multitenant.

When list users in one tenant, the roles of a user should be limited to that tenant.
but JPA returns all roles of that user in all the tetants.

How to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how you have this mapped, but you shouldn't.  Instead of caching Roles in the User which opens you upto numerous issues, query for the roles associated to a user when it is needed.  You can keep a Role->User mapping to make it easier, but remove the user->role.

Comment: One thing observed. EclipseLink re-fetches the roles for current tenant only for the first user in query results. So the roles for the first user are correct for current tenant.

Comment: Have the other Users that are read in for the current tenant already been read in through another tenant?  If so, check that the user->role mapping isn't being cached in the shared cache - you'll need to show your mapping and settings

Comment: Thanks, edited to add mappings and multitenant config. They are not cached. Fresh new start server(Tomcat), then list all users. Only the first user gets correct roles for the current tenant.